# Intuition on chart compatibility for smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M= \mathbb{R}$. Consider the charts,  $A_1 =\{(\mathbb{R}, \phi_1:t\to t)\}$ and $A_2 =\{(\mathbb{R}, \phi_1),(\mathbb{R},\phi_2:t \to t^3) \}$. Then it is clear that $M$ is a 1 dimensional manifold with respect to $A_1$ but with respect to $A_2$, the transition map $\phi^{-1}_2 o$  $\phi_1: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $t \to t^{1/3}$ is not a differentiable function at 0 and hence fails to provide a differentiable structure for $M$.

But what I am not able to understand (or confusing) is that, in $A_2$ one of the chart is simply the identity map. If we consider the chart $\{(\mathbb{R}, \phi_2)\}$, then this is a differentiable structure for $M$, however just adding an extra chart $(\mathbb{R},\phi_1)$ (which essentially is a identity map) to the chart $\{(\mathbb{R},\phi_2)\}$ fails to give a differentiable structure as described in previous paragraph. How is this idea captured via the condition that transition maps should be compatible at the non empty intersection between two different charts?

I hope I make sense in what I ask. What am I getting wrong or failing to understand properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant condition here is that $\phi_2^{-1} \circ \phi_1 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. This is what it means for two transition maps be compatible.

We don't just want manifolds. We want *smooth* manifolds. In particular, we want to be able to do calculus on our manifolds.

In particular, consider an $n$-manifold $M$. Consider a coordinate chart $\phi : U \to M$, where $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open.

The claim that $\phi$ is a "coordinate chart" should mean that $\phi : U \to Image(\phi)$ is a "smooth equivalence" between $U$ and $Image(\phi)$. We want $U$ to be locally smoothly equivalent to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

By considering the map $t \mapsto t^3$, we are considering a map that is *not* a smooth equivalence $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. This is because it doesn't have a smooth inverse.

Comment: \\By considering the map $t \mapsto t^3$, we are considering a map that is *not* a smooth equivalence $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. This is because it doesn't have a smooth inverse.\\                                                                                                              If this is so, why is $A_1 =\{(\mathbb{R}, \phi_1:t\to t^3)\}$ a smooth manifold?

Comment: @Ashok The coordinate chart $\{\mathbb{R}, \phi_1 : t \to t^3\}$ defines a completely different smooth manifold than the ordinary smooth manifold on $\mathbb{R}$. Recall that when we define a smooth manifold, we defining a set together with a notion of smoothness on that set. The manifold you provided gives a different notion of smoothness.

Comment: I have two questions. 1. What do you mean by 'ordinary smooth manifold on $\mathbb{R}$'. Do you mean, for an ordinary smooth manifold, we need at least two coordinate charts?  2. When we have two coordinate charts $t\mapsto t$ and $t\mapsto, t^3$, while the coordinate chart $t\mapsto t$ asks me to think of $\mathbb{R}$ as a straight line, the other coordinate chart $t\mapsto t^3$ asks me to think of $\mathbb{R}$ as a graph of $t\mapsto t^3$. Is this incompatibility in charts the cause of $\mathbb{R}$ with the above two coordinate charts failing to be a smooth manifold? Is my intuition correct?

Comment: @Ashok (1) When I refer to "the ordinary smooth manifold on $\mathbb{R}$", I refer to the smooth structure that contains the identity map $t \mapsto t$ as a coordinate chart. (2) Your intuition appears to be correct. It is the incompatibility of the two charts that stops the combination of them from giving a smooth structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One final question. Isn't $\mathbb{R}$ with the coordinate chart $t\mapsto t^3$ a smooth manifold as per your definition? If so, may I know your defn. of a smooth manifold?

Comment: @Ashok Yes. It is a smooth manifold. But it is a totally different smooth manifold than $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual smooth structure.